dd copies different block count
First, since some may ask, the XUbuntu system is 24.04
I issue a request using the command dd to copy a number of blocks, the response is two less than that number of blocks - with no errors.  Why the difference?
Before the dd command, I use isoinfo:
$ isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
Application id: NERO BURNING ROM
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 303507
Joliet with UCS level 3 found
NO Rock Ridge present

I then run dd:
$ dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 of=a.iso count=303507
303505+0 records in
303505+0 records out
621578240 bytes (622 MB, 593 MiB) copied, 133.864 s, 4.6 MB/s

Why the two block difference?

Is the behavior any different if you add iflag=fullblock ?

@steeldriver, tried again with iflag=fullblock - the results were identical.

I've had a few other instances of this two block discrepancy.  In this specific instance, I've found a copy of the same files/directories in a folder on my system environment.  A comparison of the files shows the file contents are identical.

I would guess that it takes 2 blocks (or a block and a spare copy) to contain the metadata that describes the disc (the information dumped by isoinfo). dd just copied data from the "disk-looking thing" at /dev/sr0, not the metadata.
